# Forcing string literal argument to cause std::string class template deduction

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to write a class template, which is able to hold different types. However, I want to avoid specializations of type `char*` or `char[]`. Character strings should always be `std::string`. The code below is what I have so far. However, writing `Scalar("hello")` yields `T = char[6]` and not `T = std::string`. I could write `Scalar<std::string>("hello")` or `Scalar(std::string("hello"))` to work around the problem. My question is, is there a way to modify the code below such that writing `Scalar("hello")` works as intended and the class still has only one template parameter?

```
template <typename T>
class Scalar {
public:

explicit Scalar(const T& val);

};
```

Comment: @MarekR I am porting a library that I didn't write myself from Python to C++. I'd like that the Python and C++ code look, except from low-level classes, such as this one, more or less the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (c++17) might help:

```
template <std::size_t N>
Scalar(const char(&)[N]) -> Scalar<std::string>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WdreEbeK1).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [std::string_literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Scalar {
public:
    explicit Scalar(const T& val) {}
};

int main()
{
   using namespace std::string_literals;    
   Scalar test("hello"s);
}
```

Of course, the use should already be aware to use the literal `"s`
to convert the string-literal to `std::string`